# The SA user (of the MSSQL database) password changes everyday

Tags: windows, sql-server

The SA user (of the MSSQL database) password changes everyday. I have disabled password policy and password expiration. Still no luck, everyday it happens

Any idea?

Comment: Voting to close here - this belongs to dba.stackexchange.com - if enough people agree it will be moved ;) Btw., neither password policy nor expiration are CHANGING the password, so that deactivations are as useless as telling us what you had for breakfast. Password CHANGES Are always coming from a SQL command that someone issues.

Comment: I don't think it belongs on DBA.se, I think it's unclear.  If it changes, you need to address what is changing it (API, another user, etc.).  I know of some 3rd-party software that does this, but there is no such feature in MSSQL.  We'd need to know why the password changed to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a DDL trigger to fire off of the alter_login event and capture the event_data to a table. This way, you can find out who's changing it when and, possibly, where from.